# Using TypeWriter animation in TextView

Tags: java, android, animation, textview

I want to use a TypeWriter animation every time a string from my array is shown.

And I use a Texview and a Button to display them, one after the other :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vibrator.vibrate(50);
            txt.startAnimation(scale);
            if(nextSentenceId < sentences.length){
                txt.setText(sentences[nextSentenceId]);
                ++nextSentenceId;
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried to use a TypeWriter class that I found, this one :

```
public class TypeWriterTextView extends TextView {

private CharSequence sequence;
private int mIndex;
private long delay = 150; //default is 150 milliseconds

public TypeWriterTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TypeWriterTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        setText(sequence.subSequence(0, mIndex++));
        if (mIndex <= sequence.length()) {
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Display text with type writer animation
 * @param txt content will be displayed
 */
public void displayTextWithAnimation(CharSequence txt) {
    sequence = txt;
    mIndex = 0;

    setText("");
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
}

/**
 * Change the delay value with this method
 * @param m
 */
public void setCharacterDelay(long m) {
    delay = m;
}  }
```

(source of the code : http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/10/android-tip-type-writer-animation.html )

But I don't know how to use it in my OnClickListener. I want to use it in the place of the

```
      txt.startAnimation(scale);
```

but how? Is there a way to create an anim ressource file for this kind of animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that the `View` in the layout file is a `TypeWriterTextView`, not just a plain `TextView`.

Next, the variable *txt* in your Java code has to be a `TypeWriterTextView` as well.

Then you should be able to make use of the typewriter feature as follows

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        vibrator.vibrate(50);
        // you said you don't want to use the scale animation any more
        // txt.startAnimation(scale);
        if(nextSentenceId < sentences.length){
            // To get the String from the resource id,
            // you need a Context. Since every View has one:
            Context ctx = txt.getContext();
            String sentence = ctx.getResources().getString(sentences[nextSentenceId]);
            // Now pass the String (which is a kind of CharSequence)
            // to the TypeWriterTextView method
            txt.displayTextWithAnimation(sentence);
            ++nextSentenceId;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to display the strings that are contained in the final int[] sentences, how can I do that by using the TypeWriterTextView?

Comment: @Emma.bk - please see my edit, and let me know if this worked

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks to you! I have another question if you can help me again: How can I manage the second click on the button? The first time that I press it start the typewriter animation, the second time it pass to the next string available. But I want to make the second click a way to display the full sentence before passing to the next one.

Comment: @Emma.bk - do you want the full text to be displayed for a while (how long?) before it is automatically substituted by the next one (this again with typewriter animation)? Then you can show the full text with [TextView.setText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) - NOTE: this method takes a string resource id! - and use [Handler.postDelayed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) to trigger a delayed display of the next line in typewriter mode